# styled-components override props type when extending component with as

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have an `Input` base component and then I want to create a `Textarea` extending it.

```js
type InputProps {
  name: string;
}

const Input = styled.input.attrs((props) => ({name: props.name, id: props.name})<InputProps>``;

const Textarea = styled(Input).attrs({as: "textarea"})``;
```

Now when I want to use the `Textarea` with an `onChange` handler Im getting type conflicts:

```js
const onChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLTextareaElement>) => {};

<Textara name="text" onChange={onChange} />
```

Produces:

```
Error: Type '(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void' is not assignable to type ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>'.
```

How can I solve this problem?
Im currently using a variable to to share my CSS between the same components but thats more of a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Way 01:** apply `as` directly on `Textarea` to have a more precise guess on the type in compile time

```js
const Textarea = styled(Input)``;

// still the input is input element so the guessing of the type will include HTMLInputElement
const onChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> & React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {}

<Textarea as="textarea" name="text" onChange={onChange} />
```

**Way 02:** use `HTMLElement` to cover all html elements and cast the type inside `onChange`

```js
const Textarea = styled(Input).attrs({as: "textarea"})``;

const onChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    const { value } = e.target as HTMLTextAreaElement
    console.log(value)
};

<Textarea name="text" onChange={onChange} />
```

Comment: So there is no "elegant" way without type conversions?

Comment: I think it will be hard as in styled component doc https://styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop, the `as` prop is doing its job at runtime. it will be hard for typescript to recognise the REAL change in compile time. Way01 is the closest one already.